# VIM function to generate a tag , how to center the cursor position after output

Tags: vim

I tried to use a simple function to echo XML tags:

```
func! SayTag()
    let tagName = input("Tag: ")
    return "<" . tagName . ">" . "<" . tagName . ">"
endfunc
```

And bind to:

`imap \tag <C-R>=SayTag()<CR>`

But after output , the cursor was after the tags , e.g `< TAG > < /TAG > _CURSOR_`

How can i set the cursor position , dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like very much the following solution but I was exploring your problem a bit because I couldn't think about a simple solution:

```
func! GetTag()
  call inputsave()
  let g:tagName = input("Tag: ")
  call inputrestore()
endfunc

imap \t <esc>:call GetTag()<CR>:exe "normal! i<".tagName."></".tagName.">"<CR>bba
```

It should work fine, you can read docs [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#input%28%29) (see the latest example). By the way, if you're planning to write a lot of XML or HTML I would suggest you to take a look at the following plugins:

- [sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup)
- [zencoding.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981)

They will save you a lot of typing.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible implementation, using a little nicer of a map.

```
function! GetTag()
    let tag = input("Tag: ")
    execute "normal! i<".tag."></".tag.">"
    execute "normal! " . repeat('h', strlen(tag)+2)
endfunction

inoremap \tag <C-o>:call GetTag()<enter>
```

However, I strongly agree that you will save tons of time using plugins that were meant for this sort of thing instead.

Edit: removed unnecessary for loop.